# Pass 1 D array to a function that takes 2 D array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function that takes 2 D character array as parameter

```
class listview{

    int numColumn;

    void func(char** data)
    {
    }
};
```

The func does not take dimensions, because it is fixed as a data member in the object of which it is member. Its job is to insert a row consisting of a number of columns  in a list view.

I want to pass a single 1 D character array to the function because this list view has only 1 column

```
listview obj;
obj.func(String("Test").GetStr());        //GetStr() returns a char array
```

How to do it?

Comment: Note that `char **` does not denote a 2D array.

Comment: Note that usually function takes char** if it wish to change the char* it self (like allocating / freeing data) but not necessary.

Comment: Let's have some more information about this function. Does it really take "an array"? What does it do? What does the documentation say? How do you usually use it? I feel like I wish I'd close-voted rather than answered, now.

Comment: This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: @Armen: I generally frown upon that. That said, I usually do it anyway... and here, I have!

Comment: The function takes multiple strings(char arrays) and inserts them into a List View. Now I want to insert a row in List View with only One column. So I want to send only one string but the function is supposed to take an array of strings. Hence the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends entirely on the function and what it does. Why does it take a `char**`? Perhaps because it takes an output or an input/output parameter? Or perhaps it treats the parameter as a 2D character map(this is unlikely since it doesn't take the dimensions). How does it interpret its parameter? Does it index the pointer passed? All these questions need to be answered.

In the simplest case of the input/output parameter, I'd recommend this:

```
char* myArray = ...;
f(&myArray); //pass the address
```

If it's just an output parameter, then I presume the argument needn't be initialized;

```
char* myArray; 
//possibly allocate memory, depends on what f does
f(&myArray);
```

Comment: +1: This is the best possible answer, given that the question currently doesn't specify what the function needs to do.

Comment: Yes, the function takes a 2D array, it does not take the dimensions because it is a member function of an object that stores the dimensions

Comment: @Sumit: What object? If it uses internal state of an object, then the object must be passed in one way or another. I mean, the function should take a reference to the object, or, be a member function of the class. You don't happen to have a global object that has some magic properties in it, do you?

Comment: @Sumit: In any case, my solution will work if the stored size is 1.

Comment: yes, you are right, I was trying it before directly without first storing it in a temporary char* variable, so it was giving problem

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple:

```
String s("Test");
char *cstr = s.GetStr(); 
func(&cstr);
```

By the way, `char*` is not 1D array. Its pointer to `char`. Similarly, `char**` is not 2D array, its pointer to pointer to `char`.

---

**CAUTION**

Don't write this<sup>1</sup>:

```
char *cstr = String("Test").GetStr(); 
func(&cstr);
```

The `String` object gets destroyed at the end of the expression, so what `cstr` may points to, doesn't exist when you call `func()`. And that pushes you into the world of *undefined behaviour*.

<sup>I'm assuming that `String` class is correctly implemented.</sup>

Comment: Define "correctly implemented". Do you mean "like `std::string`"? Do you mean "the way I think it should be"?

Comment: @Tomalak: For example, if the destructor of `String` doesn't free the memory which `GetStr()` returns, then using `cstr` after String gets  destroyed, wouldn't invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps this `String` were to use a _static_ result for a C-style string.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually passing `pointer to pointer to char`, not an array.

The closest you can get to what you want to do is to get a `pointer to char` representing a C-style string, and pass a pointer to *that*.

```
String str("Test");
char* c_str = str.GetStr();
func(&c_str);
```

Unfortunately, it's not clear from your provided code as to how `func` knows how many "elements" are in the outer "array"; consequently this may or may not be safe, and you should look at the documentation for `func`.

Even an example of how you *usually* use the function would be helpful.

Comment: If everything is correctly implemented, then after this line : `char* c_str = String("Test").GetStr();`.  The pointer `c_str` points to object, which doens't exist anymore.

Comment: Even if `String` is `std::string`, even then my comment is true!

Answer (score 0):

```
char **data // It's a pointer to a pointer (regardless the number of Ds)
```

what "func" want's is a pointer to a pointer (or array).

so:

```
String st("Hello");
char *temp = st.GetStr()); 
func(&temp);
```